# UI not loading until I resize the app window or move it to floating window

Tags: android, kotlin

I got a problem until the window isn't resized the app doesn't load its UI I don't know how to counter this problem.

this is loginActivity.kt is from where app start and than it goes to mainActivity

here is the mainActivity.kt file

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        userList = ArrayList()
        adapter = UserAdapter( this, userList )
        mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        userRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView)
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        userRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        mDbRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear()
                for( postSnapshot in snapshot.children ){
                    val currentUser = postSnapshot.getValue((User::class.java))
                    if( mAuth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid ) {
                        userList.add(currentUser!!)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })


    }
```

This is manifest files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SimpleChatApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have changed the mainActivity to loginActivity to start the app from there.

Kindly let me know if there are any more files or correction needed

Answer (score 0):

replace this  TODO("Not yet implemented") with some code or just remove it